When you repeat shema must you have kavanah
So shema requires a lot of kavanot: having in mind the mitzvah of shema, loving Gd, willing to die for Gd, reward and punishment, tzizit, yetziat mitzrayim. Plus there’s the halachot of saying it slow and not running certain words together
So suppose you’re attending a 9:00 minyan so you correctly say the shema before you start praying (since by the time you get up to it the time will have passed). Now when you get up to the shema in Tefilah, given that you were already yotzei the mitzvah, would you be allowed to disregard all the kavanot and even run along words together if let’s say the minyan is going fast and you want to keep up with them?
The same could be aksed this way- suppose you’re praying maariv early and will have to repeat shema later anyway. So now while I am saying shema, must I indeed still have all the kavanot in mind and not slur my words together, or is it fine if you do?

The two questions (morning and night) are not necessarily equivalent: the late second shema in the morning is not fulfilling the mitzvah of keriat shema, but the early first shema at night might be (according to Rabbeinu Tam).

@JoelK he holds even when you pray before tzeit it counts??

If you recited Shema before you started praying, then you technically aren’t obligated to repeat it at all (Orach Chaim 60:2)

@CuriousYid Yes he does. As long as it’s after pelag hamincha. Check out the first tosafot in Berachot.

One should never slur words or say things without kavana at any point when speaking with God.

Duplicate and no answer
